# OpenCV Error -211 specified aspect ratio is incorrect, cvStereoCalibration (C)

Tags: c, opencv

I'm trying to write a function that uses stored image pairs to calibrate the stereo camera. Code is written in C. I get the error message

> OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (The specified aspect ratio (= cameraMatrix[0][0] / cameraMatrix[1][1]) is incorrect) in cvCalibrateCamera2, file /home/daniel/opencv/opencv-2.4.13/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp, line 1602
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /home/daniel/opencv/opencv-2.4.13/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:1602: error: (-211) The specified aspect ratio (= cameraMatrix[0][0] / cameraMatrix[1][1]) is incorrect in function cvCalibrateCamera2

This is thrown by my call to cvStereoCalibrate, indicating that one of my parameters is incorrectly initialized/filled. I just can't seem to figure out what I did incorrectly.

The macros I used extend to the following:

BOARD_H_INNER 6

BOARD_W_INNER 9

NUM_SAVED_IMAGES 17

Code:

```
 int calibrate_camera_from_saved_images() {
    IplImage *leftFrame, *rightFrame;
    char imageName[20];

    //create objectPoints equal to N-by-3, N being the number of squares on the chess board
    //in use (BOARD_W * BOARD_H) times the number of images provided
    CvMat *objectPoints = cvCreateMat(
    BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER * NUM_SAVED_IMAGES, 3,
    CV_32FC1);

    //initialize objectPoints for cvStereoCalibrate
    int count = 0;
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SAVED_IMAGES; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < BOARD_W_INNER; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < BOARD_H_INNER; k++) {
                //alternatively use (i*BOARD_W)+(j*BOARD_H)+k instead of count -> efficiency ?

                CV_MAT_ELEM(*objectPoints, float, (i * BOARD_W_INNER) + (j * BOARD_H_INNER) + k, 0 ) =
                SQUARE_SIZE * k;
                CV_MAT_ELEM(*objectPoints, float, (i * BOARD_W_INNER) + (j * BOARD_H_INNER) + k, 1 ) =
                SQUARE_SIZE * j;
                CV_MAT_ELEM(*objectPoints, float, (i * BOARD_W_INNER) + (j * BOARD_H_INNER) + k, 2 ) = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    CvPoint2D32f *corners1 = new CvPoint2D32f[ BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER];
    CvPoint2D32f *corners2 = new CvPoint2D32f[ BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER];

    CvMat *imagePoints1 = cvCreateMat(
    BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER * NUM_SAVED_IMAGES, 2,
    CV_32FC1);
    CvMat *imagePoints2 = cvCreateMat(
    BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER * NUM_SAVED_IMAGES, 2,
    CV_32FC1);

    CvMat *nPoints = cvCreateMat(NUM_SAVED_IMAGES, 1, CV_32SC1);

    //load images and find their corners, corners are then stored
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SAVED_IMAGES; i++) {
        sprintf(imageName, "imageL%02u.png", i);
        leftFrame = cvLoadImage(imageName);
        find_chess_board(leftFrame, BOARD_W_INNER, BOARD_H_INNER, corners1);
        sprintf(imageName, "imageR%02u.png", i);
        rightFrame = cvLoadImage(imageName);
        find_chess_board(rightFrame, BOARD_W_INNER, BOARD_H_INNER, corners2);

        for (j = 0; j < (BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER); j++, count++) {
            CV_MAT_ELEM( *imagePoints1, float, count, 0 ) = corners1[j].x;
            CV_MAT_ELEM( *imagePoints1, float, count, 1 ) = corners1[j].y;
            CV_MAT_ELEM( *imagePoints2, float, count, 0 ) = corners2[j].x;
            CV_MAT_ELEM( *imagePoints2, float, count, 1 ) = corners2[j].y;
        }

        CV_MAT_ELEM(*nPoints, int, i, 0) = (BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER);
    }

    static CvMat *cameraMatrix1 = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    static CvMat *distCoeffs1 = cvCreateMat(5, 1, CV_32FC1);

    static CvMat *cameraMatrix2 = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    static CvMat *distCoeffs2 = cvCreateMat(5, 1, CV_32FC1);

    static CvSize imageSize = cvGetSize(leftFrame);

    static CvMat* R = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_64FC1);
    static CvMat* T = cvCreateMat(3,1,CV_64FC1);
    static CvMat* E = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_64FC1);
    static CvMat* F = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_64FC1);


    printf("Attempting Calibration");
    cvStereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, nPoints,
            cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, imageSize,
            R, T, E, F,
            cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER + CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5), CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST
                                  +CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH);

    cvSave("cameraMatrix1.xml", cameraMatrix1);
    cvSave("distCoeffs1.xml", distCoeffs1);
    cvSave("cameraMatrix2.xml", cameraMatrix2);
    cvSave("distCoeffs2.xml", distCoeffs2);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: After further testing, I have found out that using CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO is the cause of the error. Other flags do not cause this issue. However the output for the matrixes doesn't look like it worked.

cameraMatrix1.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<cameraMatrix1 type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    .Nan 0. .Nan 0. .Nan .Nan 0. 0. 1.</data></cameraMatrix1>
</opencv_storage>
```

Comment: I get the same error in c++, strangely enough it works in python. I am using opencv 3.1 in both languages. I am using calibrateCamera, not the stereo calibrate

Answer (score 0):

After trying out lots of different things and switching version from 2.4.13 to 2.4.7 and back, I now have code that does manage to take images, calibrate the cameras and to save the calibration values into .xml files.

The following code is to take images on which I could find all corners:

```
cvNamedWindow("CameraTestL", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("CameraTestR", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    CvCapture *captureL, *captureR;
    IplImage *frameL, *frameR;

    char imageNameL[20];
    strcpy(imageNameL, "imagel00.png");

    char imageNameR[20];
    strcpy(imageNameR, "imageR00.png");

    int i = 0;

    captureL = cvCreateCameraCapture(1);
    captureR = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);

    //resize capture from standard 640/480 to 320/240 due to USB bandwith constraints
    int res = cvSetCaptureProperty(captureL, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,
    FRAME_WIDTH);
    res = cvSetCaptureProperty(captureL, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,
    FRAME_HEIGHT);

    res = cvSetCaptureProperty(captureR, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_WIDTH);
    res = cvSetCaptureProperty(captureR, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,
    FRAME_HEIGHT);

    assert(captureL != NULL);
    assert(captureR != NULL);

    int cornerCount;

    CvSize boardSize = cvSize(BOARD_W, BOARD_H);

    while (1) {
        frameL = cvQueryFrame(captureL);
        frameR = cvQueryFrame(captureR);
        if (!frameL)
            break;
        if (!frameR)
            break;

        CvPoint2D32f* corners = new CvPoint2D32f[ BOARD_W * BOARD_H];
    //  IplImage *helperL, *helperR;
        IplImage *grayImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frameL), 8, 1);

    //  cvCopyImage(frameL, helperL);
    //  cvCopyImage(frameR, helperR);

        int found = cvFindChessboardCorners(frameL, boardSize, corners,
                &cornerCount,
                CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

        cvCvtColor(frameL, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvFindCornerSubPix(grayImage, corners, cornerCount, cvSize(11,11), cvSize(-1,-1), cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));

        cvDrawChessboardCorners(frameL, boardSize, corners, cornerCount, found);

        found = cvFindChessboardCorners(frameR, boardSize, corners, &cornerCount, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);
        cvCvtColor(frameR, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvFindCornerSubPix(grayImage, corners, cornerCount, cvSize(11,11), cvSize(-1,-1), cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));

        cvDrawChessboardCorners(frameR, boardSize, corners, cornerCount, found);

        cvShowImage("CameraTestL", frameL);
        cvShowImage("CameraTestR", frameR);
        //cvWaitKey returns value of key pressed
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        //press ESC key to break (ESC == 27)
        if (c == 27)
            break;
        if (c == 's') {

            frameL = cvQueryFrame(captureL);
            frameR = cvQueryFrame(captureR);

            sprintf(imageNameL, "imageL0%02u.png", i);
            sprintf(imageNameR, "imageR0%02u.png", i);

            cvSaveImage(imageNameL, frameL, 0);
            cvSaveImage(imageNameR, frameR, 0);

            printf("Saved image #%d\n", i);
            fflush(stdout);
            i++;
        }
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&captureL);
    cvReleaseCapture(&captureR);
    cvDestroyWindow("CameraTestL");
    cvDestroyWindow("CameraTestR");

    return 0;
```

And the following code reads the images and computes the cameraMatrixes and other parameters

```
int calibrate_camera_from_saved_images() {
IplImage *leftFrame, *rightFrame;
char imageName[20];

//create objectPoints equal to N-by-3, N being the number of squares on the chess board
//in use (BOARD_W * BOARD_H) times the number of images provided
CvMat *objectPoints = cvCreateMat(
BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER * NUM_SAVED_IMAGES, 3,
CV_32FC1);

//initialize objectPoints for cvStereoCalibrate
int count = 0;
int i, j, k;

for (i = 0; i < NUM_SAVED_IMAGES; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < BOARD_W_INNER; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < BOARD_H_INNER; k++, count++) {
            //alternatively use (i*BOARD_W)+(j*BOARD_H)+k instead of count -> efficiency ?

            CV_MAT_ELEM(*objectPoints, float, count, 0 ) =
            SQUARE_SIZE * k;
            CV_MAT_ELEM(*objectPoints, float, count, 1 ) =
            SQUARE_SIZE * j;
            CV_MAT_ELEM(*objectPoints, float, count, 2 ) = 0;
        }
    }
}

CvPoint2D32f *corners1 = new CvPoint2D32f[ BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER];
CvPoint2D32f *corners2 = new CvPoint2D32f[ BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER];

CvMat *imagePoints1 = cvCreateMat(
BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER * NUM_SAVED_IMAGES, 2,
CV_32FC1);
CvMat *imagePoints2 = cvCreateMat(
BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER * NUM_SAVED_IMAGES, 2,
CV_32FC1);

CvMat *nPoints = cvCreateMat(NUM_SAVED_IMAGES, 1, CV_32SC1);
count = 0;
//load images and find their corners, corners are then stored
for (i = 0; i < NUM_SAVED_IMAGES; i++) {
    sprintf(imageName, "imageL%002u.png", i);
    leftFrame = cvLoadImage(imageName);
    find_chess_board(leftFrame, BOARD_W_INNER, BOARD_H_INNER, corners1);
    sprintf(imageName, "imageR%002u.png", i);
    rightFrame = cvLoadImage(imageName);
    find_chess_board(rightFrame, BOARD_W_INNER, BOARD_H_INNER, corners2);

    for (j = 0; j < (BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER); j++, count++) {
        CV_MAT_ELEM( *imagePoints1, float, count, 0 ) = corners1[j].x;
        CV_MAT_ELEM( *imagePoints1, float, count, 1 ) = corners1[j].y;
        CV_MAT_ELEM( *imagePoints2, float, count, 0 ) = corners2[j].x;
        CV_MAT_ELEM( *imagePoints2, float, count, 1 ) = corners2[j].y;
    }

    CV_MAT_ELEM(*nPoints, int, i, 0) = (BOARD_W_INNER * BOARD_H_INNER);
}

static CvMat *cameraMatrix1 = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64F);
static CvMat *distCoeffs1 = cvCreateMat(5, 1, CV_32FC1);

static CvMat *cameraMatrix2 = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64F);
static CvMat *distCoeffs2 = cvCreateMat(5, 1, CV_32FC1);

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix1, float, i, 0) = 1;
    CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix1, float, i, 1) = 1;
    CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix1, float, i, 2) = 1;
    CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix2, float, i, 0) = 1;
    CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix2, float, i, 1) = 1;
    CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix2, float, i, 2) = 1;
}

static CvSize imageSize = cvGetSize(leftFrame);
static CvMat* R = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
static CvMat* T = cvCreateMat(3, 1, CV_64FC1);
static CvMat* E = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
static CvMat* F = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);

printf("Attempting Calibration\n");
fflush(stdout);
cvStereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, nPoints,
        cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, imageSize,
        R, T, E, F,
        cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER + CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
        CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH);

cvSave("cameraMatrix1.xml", cameraMatrix1);
cvSave("distCoeffs1.xml", distCoeffs1);
cvSave("cameraMatrix2.xml", cameraMatrix2);
cvSave("distCoeffs2.xml", distCoeffs2);
cvSave("RotationMatrix.xml", R);
cvSave("TransformationVector.xml", T);

return 0;
```

}

CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO still does not work though.